# How to connect to a non-secure localhost websocket on iOS?

Tags: ios, websocket, localhost

I have a Qt application which bundles a browser and an application which hosts a non-secure websocket server on port 50050. The browser tries to connect to the application via ws://127.0.0.1:50050 and this works out well on macOS. On iOS, however, the connection fails. I'd suspect this is due to iOS specific security settings – also because the dialog to allow local network usage does not show up. Please find here the list of network related security keys I applied in the Info.plist file

```
<key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key>
<string>Uses local networking to communicate settings…</string>
<key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key><true/>

<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
       <dict>
                <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
                <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia</key><true/>
                <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key><true/>
                <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key><true/>
                <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>localhost</key>
                        <dict>
                                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key><true/>
                                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key><true/>
                        </dict>
                        <key>mydomain.com</key>
                        <dict>
                                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key><true/>
                                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key><true/>
                        </dict>
                </dict>
        </dict>
```

Am I missing anything in terms of security keys or does anyone have a different suggestions how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: what error do you receive on crash?

Comment: It only says "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x88790000ffff0008)" with further details when using the send call followed by: appName`QScopedPointer<QObjectData, QScopedPointerDeleter<QObjectData> >::get: and additional assembly code.

Comment: Update: I reconfigured the websocket server to 0.0.0.0 – then I can connect from the same LAN from a different machine via ws://192.168.0.56:50050, however, I cannot connect from an external Domain http://www.myDomain.de/connectScript.html and not from the iOS app-own browser via localhost either. Also please forget about the crash which occurs for other implementational reasons.

Comment: On iOS , it is always difficult to connect to local hosted server because of server running in background . You have to switch from browser to server and back to make it happen. From internet you need some NAT to be able to connect to your device.

Comment: The server is not running in the background because it is part of the foreground app. Also the browser is part of this app which is why I don't understand the actual issue of non-connectivity.

Comment: P.S.: Also NAT is not an issue because the same script and call above (ws://192.168.0.56:50050) is triggered on the same machine in the same LAN, however, now retrieved from a remote server – again this looks like a security related issue.

Comment: After a couple of days it turns out to be an issue of addressing a non-secure websocket from a secure website. On OSX this fails on Safari only but on iOS this seens to happen with any browser. Will send a final confirmation asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS non-secure websockets (neither localhost) are not permitted in context with secure websites (https). On OSX it is permitted for any browser except Safari. The solution is to either use non-secure websites (http) or create a secure websocket on localhost if https is required.

Comment: Notably, websockets on iOS use different validation rules and cannot be overridden, so you cannot currently create a secure websocket server on iOS(since the validation rules cannot be broken, and since no CA will sign a cert for localhost). https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/74152?answerId=216724022#216724022